# C++ std::string::insert(string::iterator, char) iterator not random

Tags: c++

I am trying to insert one char in a string:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include<string>
using namespace Rcpp;

f(std::string a){
std::string::iterator i=a.begin()+1;
a.insert(i,',');
std::cout<<a<<"\n";
std::cout<<*i<<"\n";
std::cout<<*(i-1)<<"\n";
}
```

f("abcd") will print:

```
"a,bcd"
"b"
"a"
```

I supposed *(i-1) to be ",". It seems the iterator is broken here? So I shouldn't use the std::string::iterator with std::string like use std::vector::iterator with std::vector?

Thanks!

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. std::string's iterators may be invalidated after a call to `insert`.

Comment: Official text on that point: *References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a basic_string sequence may be invalidated
by the following uses of that basic_string object:
— as an argument to any standard library function taking a reference to non-const basic_string as an
argument.
— Calling non-const member functions, except operator[], at, front, back, begin, rbegin, end, and
rend.*

Comment: About the last sentence, `std::vector`'s iterators have the same problem.

Comment: This is heart breaking!@chris

Comment: @user2961927 changed my comment to an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insert operation may invalidate the iterator (because it may cause a memory reallocation, and the iterators don't magically move to the new location).

To fix this, do `i = a.insert(i, ',');`.

Also, this is nothing to do with Rcpp.

Answer (score -1):

This is because `string::iterator` is a bidirectional iterator, which means `i` points to the next and previous iterator (lets call it's members `next` and `prev`.

After the insert `i` was not modified, so it's `prev` member is still pointing to the same iterator it was pointing before (which is `a.begin()`, btw).

Comment: It's a random-access iterator (which still fulfills the requirements of a bidirectional iterator). That's not the point, though. If you have a pointer to some element in an array and you reallocate more space for the array and move it over, what do you expect the pointer to be good for? It could happen, but it's undefined behaviour either way.

Comment: I did't say the point was good or bad, I said where it was pointing to so the user could understand what happened. Iterators MAY be invalidated, but in this case it wasn't. Don't get me wrong, the iterator in the context of the string is invalid, but the pointer is still pointer to a valid memory address.